# Trying to redirect a uri to a page with parameter

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, uri

The problem I am having is i try to do 2 things

1. remove the .php from the pages
2. redirect /user/12345 to /user?id=12345

I use a HTACCESS file for this with

```
RewriteEngine On
#remove .PHP from filenames
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L] 

# Get user info for uri
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ user?UserID=$1 [L]
```

The .php is removed thats working but when I type a URL like /user/12345 I am redirected to the homepage not to the user page

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you'll need to at least rewrite to `user.php?UserID=$1`

If you can increase your mod_rewrite logging level it shows its working out in its logs, this can be helpful if you can follow what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working it was in the order of the two steps
This is the correct and working HTACCESS

```
RewriteEngine On
# Get user info for uri
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ /user.php?UserID=$1 [L]

#remove .PHP from filenames
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Thankx for the help